# Custom collection view layout attributes not being set before being applied to a cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, xcode6

I am writing my own custom layout collection view layout (minor customizations to flow layout) and to simplify a few things I am trying to subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAttributes too. Everything is working perfectly fine but when I try to apply my layout attributes in my custom cell every attribute is nil.

Cell (attributes are all nil here):

```
- (void)applyLayoutAttributes:(CustomLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributes
{
    [super applyLayoutAttributes:layoutAttributes];

    NSLog(@"layoutAttributes %@", layoutAttributes.description);

}
```

Custom Flow Layout (Attributes being applied perfectly!!!):

```
+ (Class)layoutAttributesClass
{
    return [CustomLayoutAttributes class];
}
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSArray *attributesInRect = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];

    [attributesInRect enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CustomLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if (layoutAttributes.representedElementCategory == UICollectionElementCategoryCell) {
            [self configureLayoutAttributes:layoutAttributes];
        }
    }];

    return attributesInRect;
}

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomLayoutAttributes  *layoutAttributes = (CustomLayoutAttributes *)[super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (layoutAttributes.representedElementCategory == UICollectionElementCategoryCell) {
        [self configureLayoutAttributes:layoutAttributes];
    }
    return layoutAttributes;
}

- (void)configureLayoutAttributes:(CustomLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributes
{
    CustomCollectionView *collectionView = (CustomCollectionView *)self.collectionView;

    layoutAttributes.messageTopLabelHeight = 20.0;
    layoutAttributes.messageBottomLabelHeight = 20.0;
    layoutAttributes.messageBubbleFont = _messageBubbleFont;
}
```

### Am I doing something wrong or missing something? :).

Note: I created all my cells in a storyboard, and set my custom layout in storyboard as well.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Why are you specifying `CustomLayoutAttributes` in `layoutAttributesClass` but then casting the instances to `IGChatCollectionViewLayoutAttributes`?

Comment: Sorry my fault I was trying to remove what I actually called it in place for a simpler name for purposes of this question. I will fix it.

Comment: Just paste in your code.  If you made that mistake, you might make other mistakes that make it impossible to answer your question.

Comment: Good point, your right...do you see any other mistake I may have made though?

Comment: How do you know your attributes are nil?  What's the output of the `NSLog`?  Did you override `description` in your `CustomLayoutAttributes`?

Comment: I figured out the problem...apparently UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes must conform to NSCopying and implement copyWithZone:. After doing that everything worked perfectly. That took a while to google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

figured out the problem...apparently UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes must conform to NSCopying and implement copyWithZone:. After doing that everything worked perfectly.